# Accept working copy “as is” in Subversion

Tags: svn

Is there a simple way to accept the working copy “as is” in Subversion? I would like to have the “unknown” files denoted by `?` to be added, missing files to be deleted and changed files commited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `svn commit` would commit the modified files, but for:

- the deleted files, you need first (before the commit) a command like

```
    $ svn status | grep '^\!' | sed 's/! *//' | xargs -I% svn rm %
```

- the files added (with spaces in them):

```
   $ svn status | grep "^\?" | sed -e 's/? *//' | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g' | xargs svn add
```

On recent SVN you could just `svn add --force *` (it is recursive)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single svn command that does all that at once.

Here is a simple bash script that deletes missing files:

```
for i in `svn list -R`; do if [ ! -e $i ]; then svn rm $i; fi; done
```

Answer (score 0):

If your on windows use TortiseSVN it will show you a list of all the new/deleted files and you can just select all the changes and commit.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but I need to script that.